# How do you format for thousands separator in Python?

Tags: python

I am simply trying to execute the following command in Python:

```
print("Number is", format(49000.12345,"10.2f"))
```

So I would like it to print out like 49,000.12 for the number.

My teacher taught us to put a comma in `"10.2f"` like `",10.2f"` for the thousands separator but it's not working. Could someone please tell me the correct simple way similar to that?

Thank you

Comment: @Cilyan What I don't get is, if I do ",.2f" it would work but when I do ",10.2f" it doesn't. Please could someone just show me an example at least?

Comment: According to the fomat specification mini-language page, the syntax is `format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]`. As you see the comma is expected right before the point. Try `"10,.2f"`.

Answer (score -2):

See this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/ It is the PEP introducing the ability into Python 2.7, 3.1 and later versions.